# Trouble with if/else for clicking links with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

I am trying to load a page and click either the first link with text "Buy It Now" or (if Buy It Now is unavailable) the first "Quick Bid" link.

I am using the Selenium IDE extension for Chrome (https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) and am having trouble with the if / else statement. In Chrome, when I get to the page where "Buy It Now" or "Quick Bid" are found, I try manually inserting the if statement with the target

```
linkText=Buy It Now
```

On playback, when I get to this line, I get:

> Failed: Unexpected identifier

I also tried the if-target:

```
linkText=Buy It Now == true
```

But I get the same error.

In case it was the IDE, I also tried the same macro, but with Katalon Recorder. It gives a similar error:

> [error] SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A linktext is an a tag with the text of the value you put in.

Comment: If the linktext value is found on the page, shouldn't that return "true" and let the if/else continue? If not, what is the correct way to do this kind of check?